# How do I build Qt5.6 with xmlpatterns module enabled?

Tags: qt, qtdeclarative

I've found out that XmlListModel QML element resides in `qtdeclarative` git submodule and that to include it in the build I need somehow to enable `xmlpatterns` module of Qt (according to `qtdeclarative/src/imports/imports.pro` file). The question is how do I do that? The answer should definitely be simple and obvious but Google doesn't give it among the most popular results.

Answer (score 1):

just add framework in you .pro file:
    `QT += core xml xmlpatterns`

Comment: Mmm, I don't know Qt very well, I never use it.... What I have is Qt's sources, I run perl init-repository then configure and then make. Could you explain a little bit further which .pro file you mean?